# Develop custom auto-complete plugin for MS Word using n-gram language model

Tags: autocomplete, nlp, n-gram, statistics, text-analysis

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to implement a customization to Microsoft Word which will provide word prediction (auto-complete) option as the user types, based on n-gram language models built from a large corpus of training data.

I work in an office where we transcribe audio files. All the material is discourses of a single person speaking, and we have several 1000 transcriptions already done and several 1000 more to do. We have experimented with ASR solutions, but have found that its actually more effort to correct the auto-transcribed text, than it is to transcribe it from scratch.

I thought that we could come up with a solution using just the language model component, and use it to assist the transcribers as they type. The users could choose to type some of the words fully and just the first few letters of other words, and quickly scroll through the list of most probable completions using the space-bar, in such a way that they could transcribe as fast as the audio is being played back.

Would love to hear anybody's thoughts - specifically on how best to generate the LM and how to plug it in.

I also came across this awesome paper on incorporating topic related probabilities http://noah.coccaro.com/publications/thesis.pdf

Comment: my suggestion is, if you think it's an awesome paper, try asking the authors for the code. Or try reimplementing their algorithm =)

Comment: Any update on this one? Sounds interesting.